# Option symbol 'GOOG' not working in YQL

Tags: yahoo-finance, yql

I am trying to retrieve options data from Yahoo Finance using YQL. The very strange problem is that I can download the desired options data for other symbols such as AAPL (Apple) and MSFT (Microsoft), but not for GOOG (Google).

Here's my query and the result. Obviously I can retrieve data for AAPL and MSFT, but GOOG is missing. This happens not only with yahoo.finance.option_contracts, but also with all other option-related tables including yahoo.finance.options. I am pretty sure that this is not something related to the query limits, since the query shown below is expected to retrieve only less than 10 results for GOOG.

```
select * from yahoo.finance.option_contracts where symbol in ( 'GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT')

{
 "query": {
  "count": 2,
  "created": "2014-03-03T15:00:45Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "url": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "0",
     "execution-stop-time": "1",
     "execution-time": "1",
     "content": "http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.option_contracts.xml"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "4",
     "execution-stop-time": "1057",
     "execution-time": "1053",
     "content": "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=MSFT"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "5",
     "execution-stop-time": "3571",
     "execution-time": "3566",
     "content": "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=AAPL"
    },
    {
     "error": "Connect Failure",
     "execution-start-time": "5",
     "execution-stop-time": "10017",
     "execution-time": "10012",
     "content": "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=GOOG"
    },
    {
     "error": "Connect Failure",
     "execution-start-time": "5",
     "execution-stop-time": "10017",
     "execution-time": "10012",
     "content": "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=GOOG"
    }
   ],
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "javascript": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "3",
     "execution-stop-time": "1074",
     "execution-time": "1070",
     "instructions-used": "18571",
     "table-name": "yahoo.finance.option_contracts"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "3",
     "execution-stop-time": "3616",
     "execution-time": "3612",
     "instructions-used": "31142",
     "table-name": "yahoo.finance.option_contracts"
    },
    "Exception: Read timed out, url: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=GOOG",
    {
     "execution-start-time": "3",
     "execution-stop-time": "10017",
     "execution-time": "10013",
     "instructions-used": "31142",
     "table-name": "yahoo.finance.option_contracts"
    }
   ],
   "user-time": "10018",
   "service-time": "19447",
   "build-version": "0.2.2157"
  },
  "results": {
   "option": [
    {
     "symbol": "AAPL",
     "contract": [
      "2014-03",
      "2014-04",
      "2014-05",
      "2014-06",
      "2014-07",
      "2014-10",
      "2015-01",
      "2016-01"
     ]
    },
    {
     "symbol": "MSFT",
     "contract": [
      "2014-03",
      "2014-04",
      "2014-05",
      "2014-06",
      "2014-07",
      "2014-10",
      "2015-01",
      "2016-01"
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

In sum, every time I try to retrieve options data for GOOG, I only get null result with the error of 'Read Timed Out'. For other option symbols such as AAPL and MSFT, I get what I desire.

Anyone knows why this is so?

Comment: I'm getting a "Server Hangup" message when I try and go directly to the [finance.yahoo link](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=GOOG)

Comment: Now it appears to be up and running (I think it's just a fickle service right now)

Comment: Nah, I'm stilling getting no result with the symbol 'GOOG'. Now it doesn't say 'Read Timed Out', but there's no data retrieved inside the 'results'. Is this a server-side problem?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? It's doing the same for me (i.e. no results for GOOG, but you also get no results if you just put GOOG in through the UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must have to do with Google the company trading under **TWO** stickers (See http://finance.yahoo.com/news/google-trades-under-2-tickers-225300863.html): GOOG and GOOGL.

YQL doesn't recognize GOOG, but will accept the new ticker **GOOGL**. I suspect the YQL query errors out on getting unexpectedly two tickers instead of one when looking for just GOOG.

If you request a GOOG quote on Yahoo!Finance, it works.